# Is there a vim plugin that provides syntax highlighting for Stan?

Tags: stan

Is there syntax highlighting support for Stan in Vim?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a big list question, too many questions, one question is primarily opinion-based, and two more ask for a recommendation of an off-site resource.

Comment: @minitech Okay. I've edited the question to focus specifically on Vim. Now it is no longer asking for a list.

Answer (score 3):

[maverickg created stan.vim](https://github.com/maverickg/stan.vim) which provides syntax highlighting for Vim.

Here's a screen shot

[image: stan syntax highlighting in vim]

Note that the core stan site also has an Emacs mode called [stan-mode](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan-mode).